# How is Cadence an actor framework?

Tags: cadence-workflow

How is Cadence an actor framework? What components in Cadence make it into an actor framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would rather say that Cadence can be used to implement Actor model.

If you model Cadence workflow as “actor” , the three requirements can be full filled :

- a workflow can start other workflows
- a workflow can send signals to another workflow as FIFO which will work as “mailbox” of actor
- a workflow can supervise other workflow and decide what todo to recover from any failure

However, Cadence framework is far more powerful than the above three. So I won’t limit myself to use Cadence like that.

Cadence provides a very high level abstraction for long running business which is more natural to use. It has concepts of activity, timer, signal, query, search attributes, etc

Again, don’t limit your usage within actor models. It’s not going to that useful for using Cadence. Cadence is a revolutionary architecture/solution for long running business like OOP has changed our ways of writing code for business.